# How to set width of time picker?

Tags: jquery, css

I have used the following code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<script 
      src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js">
</script>

<script>
  var time = "9";

  $(function() {
    $('#itime').timepicker({
      minTime: time,
      maxTime: '7:00pm',
      'timeFormat': 'H:i:s'
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 10px;" onclick="shwtmpkr()">
  <input type="text" id="itime" name="itime" class="form-control" 
         placeholder="Booking Time" style="background-color:white" /> @*
  <input type='text' id="rTime" name="rTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Booking Date" 
         style="background-color:white" readonly="" />*@
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your exact problem. Please explain more

Comment: 1- Actualy I am using timepicker but its showing its default width. And I want to increase that width as same as input element. Simultaniously if i add readonly attribute to input element

Comment: 2- Simultaniousy if i add readonly attribute to input field then also it is not showing timepicker

Comment: 1- what width you want it to be? 2- if you will add read only the pointer event will stop which in turn will stop time picker.. Why you want readonly on that ?

Comment: 1- Suppose i want to set width of timepicker 90px using css then how can i achieve that? 2- Because i don't want to make user to input manual values as date to avoid wrong input that is why i want to make that input element as readonly.

Comment: 1- the width of your input will be the with of your time picker , So change the width of your input to change widthh of time picker.
2- So what I have understood after 1st time is selected then only 2nd option can be selected to select the date?

Answer (score 0):

Set width to input element..  `width:80px`

```js
 var time = "9";

  $(function() {
    $('#itime').timepicker({
      minTime: time,
      maxTime: '7:00pm',
      'timeFormat': 'H:i:s'
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 10px;" >
  <input type="text" id="itime" name="itime" class="form-control" placeholder="Booking Time" style="background-color:white;width:80px" /> @*
  <input type='text' id="rTime" name="rTime" class="form-control" placeholder="Booking Date" style="background-color:white" readonly="" />*@
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```